# How to install Virtual ethernet for kernel 3.19?

Tags: kernel, vmware

xUbuntu 14.04

LINUX Kernel : 3.19.4-031904

VMware Player 7.1.0 build-2496824

running vplayer show Virtual ethernet failed

I try the method

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#Using_DKMS_to_manage_the_modules

but shell return

```
Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vmware-modules/11/source ->
                 /usr/src/vmware-modules-11

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:

cleaning build area....

make KERNELRELEASE=3.19.4-031904-generic all....(bad exit status: 2)

ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for vmware-modules: 11 not found

Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.19.4-031904-generic 
(x86_64)

Consult /var/lib/dkms/vmware-modules/11/build/make.log for more information.
```

My [make.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10876589/) and [vmware-6609.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10876596).

Comment: You probably need to download the latest VMWare Player. It worked for me on Ubuntu for the Player version 7.1.0 build-249682, kernel version 3.19.0-15-generic and I have applied the following [steps](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#3.19_kernels_and_up)

Comment: Sorry just noticed that you had the same version of VMWare Player. Then please make sure that you have applied the right steps as your link to the steps is different from mine.